# What's the best way to convert various file types to PDF in NextJS when fs is not supported on the browser?

Tags: typescript, file, npm, file-conversion

i'm building a webapp using NextJS, my goal is to convert as much as possible types (doc, docx, xls, .txt ...) to pdf.

I tried to create a separate npm package with tsup to handle that conversion, then return the file as pdf, but unfortunately it didn't work out, because fs is not supported on the browser. my question is : can i do the conversion thing in the client side ? is there any way to not setup a nodejs express server to handle that ? or must i do that in my Nextjs server ? thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.